# MOTD on Pi OS Lite

Tags: ssh

Removed `/etc/motd`.
However, if I create it then it is displayed *twice*.

Added some scripts in `/etc/update-notd.d` all of which run correctly when started from the command line. For example `run-parts /etc/update-notd.d` shows the expected motd.

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have `PrintMotd yes`.

But when I log in: nothing!
No messages in `/var/log/syslog`.

What could be wrong?

**Update**

I found `/var/run/motd.dynamic.new` and `cat`ing it shows output from four of my five scripts in `update-motd.d`. If I move it to `motd.dynamic` then its contents are shown on login.

Therefore it seems that:

- I need to regenerate `/var/run/motd.dynamic`,
- sometimes it is generated automatically but for me today it isn't.

I notice that the command `update-motd` isn't installed. Should it be?

If I remove `/var/run/motd.dynamic.new` and log out and back in then it reappears -- with the same four out of five parts.

Comment: Did you restart the SSH daemon?

Comment: I did `sudo systemctl restart sshd`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A new motd script will not run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681329/a-new-motd-script-will-not-run)