# A new motd script will not run

Tags: debian, motd

I created a new script `99-wlan0-RWB` in `/etc/update-motd.d` which is world executable like all the others. It works when run on its own or via `run-parts`, but is not run when logging in: what's wrong? (I have the same problem on a Raspberry Pi where *none* of the scripts in `update-motd.d` run.) (Nothing in `/var/log/syslog`.)

```
$ ssh root@mini31
Linux mini31 4.19.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.208-1 (2021-09-29) x86_64
External IP: xx.yyy.zzz.www
 ______________________________________
/ 1st graffitiist: QUESTION AUTHORITY! \
|                                      |
\ 2nd graffitiist: Why?                /
 --------------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
df: 43G (81%)
    O2: 1.65 GB / 3.3 GB
Lebara: 6.49 MB / 66 MB
up: 10 days, la: 1:0.11, 5:0.14, 15:0.10
mssql tempdb.mdf is 515M
CPU temp.: +52.0
No mail.
mini31 # cd /etc/update-motd.d/
mini31 # ./98-data
df: 43G (81%)
    O2: 1.65 GB / 3.3 GB
Lebara: 6.49 MB / 66 MB
up: 10 days, la: 1:0.18, 5:0.15, 15:0.10
mssql tempdb.mdf is 515M
CPU temp.: +50.0°C
mini31 # ./99-wlan0-RWB
wlan0 is up
mini31 #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and it's taken me 3 nights to work out what was going on.  But you have a capital letter in your file name.  Rename your file to one with all lower case letters and it should start working.  Its frustrating as this was not called out in the documentation regarding naming conventions (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/update-motd.5.htm)

Answer (score 0):

With newer systems the MOTD is controlled through `pam_motd` in the PAM authentication/authorisation subsystem (see `man pam_motd`). It's triggered through the `sshd` and `login` facilities when a session is opened.

Relevant entries from `/etc/pam.d/sshd`

```
# Print the message of the day upon successful login.
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so  noupdate
```

The `/run/motd.dynamic` file referenced in the first entry is created by processing executable scripts in the directory `/etc/update-motd.d/`, meaning that it is updated each time any and every user logs in.

The second entry simply outputs the content of the fixed `/etc/motd` file.

Now as to why your script is not run: I have two suggestions:

1. Permissions on the directory and/or files associated with `/etc/update-motd.d` are too lax.  (I don't know if this might be an issue, but seeing as they are run by root it should be one.)
2. Entries in the PAM definition files are missing or commented out

Comment: That's interesting... on my Rpi OS buster the only file in `/etc/init` is `paxctld.conf` - which doesn't seem to have anything to do with `motd` - it bills itself as `"PaX flags maintenance daemon"`. I run the "Lite"/headless distro.

Comment: This can't be right because when I edit an existing file the changes take effect immediately, i.e., at the next login -- no restart is necessary. And anyway, I've rebooted the Pi many times but still no `motd`.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough new answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Following is a method to update `/etc/motd` at login. I've tested it on my RPi OS buster system, and it works for me. There are other methods (e.g. using `pam_motd`) that may also accomplish the same or similar results. As it turns out, the simple MOTD has become fairly complex while I wasn't looking. The [Debian Wiki for `motd`](https://wiki.debian.org/motd) covers most of the details for Debian-based distros (e.g. Raspberry Pi OS), and it also summarizes how `motd` is handled in several other common distros.

One method to generate/refresh your `/etc/motd` file at login is simply to run a command to update it at login. For `bash` login scripts may be run from the file `~/.profile`.

Here's a simple example that works on my system from an SSH login: a one-line command sequence added to the end of user `pi`'s `~/.profile`. Since modification of `/etc/motd` requires `root` privileges, writing to that file may be most conveniently done via `tee` under `sudo`:

```
printf "Hello from .profile for  %s.\n" $USER | sudo tee -a /etc/motd >/dev/null
```

The `-a` option for `tee` appends to `/etc/motd` which may not suit many use-cases; an overwrite (equivalent to `>`) is invoked by simply omitting the `-a` argument. Also, the redirect to `/dev/null` prevents the MOTD from being *repeated* in the login display in the terminal.

Notes:

1. The `sudo` invocation works here because user `pi` has the `NOPASSWD` setting in the `sudoers` file - currently the *default* setup for RPi OS buster.
2. The MOTD display for SSH logins [is said to be controlled](https://wiki.debian.org/motd) in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` via (`PrintMotd`). ***However***, for Debian distributions this option must be set to `no` as the `sshd` default (`yes`) results in outputting the MOTD twice - once from `sshd`, and again from `pam_motd`.
3. Read the notes in `~/.profile` re. existence of `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`.

Comment: There is no `/etc/motd` file. Wasn't that abandoned years ago? 
My understanding is that the output of `run-parts /etc/update-motd.d` should be the login message and should be evaluated on every login so as to get up to date data.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough: `/etc/motd` **does** exist on my system: **RPi OS buster**.  I'm not making this up - I tested the answer I proposed before I posted it. If your system **does not** have `/etc/motd`, please edit your question to explain which distro you need help with. You mentioned in your Q that you *also* had the problem with Raspberry Pi

Comment: The question is about `/etc/update-motd.d` which you appear not to have even understood let alone answered.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough: You seem to be more interested in demeaning my answer, and insulting me, than in accomplishing your stated objective. That's fine, I won't waste our time further. But I must say that for someone who said that `/etc/motd` no longer existed, you seem to have self-promoted your expertise extravagantly.  :)